# ThisBuild ignored for plugin settingKey

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

This issue is connected with my troubles with `sbt-scapegoat` but I would like to understand this thing globally.

So, `sbt-scapegoat` defines a setting `scapegoatVersion` and config `scapegoat`. Short and complete source code is availible [here](https://github.com/sksamuel/sbt-scapegoat/blob/b42d8f886256a7d9551df658634610718c0df82c/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/scapegoat/sbt/ScapegoatSbtPlugin.scala).

When I set `scapegoatVersion in ThisBuild := "1.3.0"` it is ignored:

```
> scapegoat:scapegoatVersion
[info] frontend/scapegoat:scapegoatVersion
[info]  1.0.0
[info] backend/scapegoat:scapegoatVersion
[info]  1.0.0
[info] {.}/scapegoat:scapegoatVersion
[info]  1.3.0
```

I understand it is so, because `scapegoatVersion := "1.0.0"` is imported for every project from `autoImport` object, and such setting is more precise than `scapegoatVersion in ThisBuild` so overrides it.

My question is: how such default value should be defined in a plugin to allow global overrides with `ThisBuild` or `Global`.

**@edit:**
I've found that `version` setting i `Defaults.scala` is defined using `:==` instead of `:=`. Is this a trick I'm looking for? Sadly it's not documented and moreover, it's private to `sbt` package.

Answer (score 0):

I think by applying the `scapegoatVersion` to `ThisBuild` you are setting it only for the "parent project" (also identified as `{.}`).

From the logs you pasted it looks like you got 2 submodules, for which the default `scapegoatVersion` still applies.

Have you tried defining the version in some commonSettings variable and apply it to the submodules? Something along the lines of:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scapegoatVersion := "1.3.0"
)

lazy val backend = (project in file("backend"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  ...

lazy val frontend = (project in file("frontend"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  ...
```

Comment: That's the exact thing I want to avoid by using ThisBuild, so I don't have to specify it in all modules.

Comment: Something else you could try is `scapegoatVersion in Global := "1.3.0"`  .